# Recognize chatbox on game screenshots

Tags: neural-network, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network, object-detection

I have videos from a computer game. In this computer game, during the rounds, there is a chat box where players can write messages. I want to read the content of this chatbox.

[image: Example Image]

Difficulties are here:

- The chatbox is always different in size, depending on how much has been written.
- Sometimes there is no chatbox at all, because nobody writes anything.
- Sometimes the chatbox is covered by other HUD windows.
- Parts of the video are in the menu or on the desktop. Not all are in the game.

At first I thought I would break the problem down into individual steps.

1. Split video into frames
2. use an image classifier to see if it is a gamescreen at all.
3. cut out approximately where the chatbox could be.
4. detect with an object detection in which area the chat is and cut out the picture like this. So that no other HUD elements are in the image.
5. use Tesseract for the actual text detection.

But I think this is very complicated. Would it be better to do 2,3,4 directly with object detection? So something like this:

1. Split videos into frames
2. detect if there is a chat at all and if so where
3. crop
4. text recognition

Before I label 10.000 images I wanted to ask what is the right approach.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be the right general approach, however, I recommend to cut down into smaller pieces in order to be very efficient.

First of all, you should ensure that the most important function, text recognition, works well: If you have done good area detection and good screen recognition, but you don't have good text recognition, you would have lost time. Furthermore, there are always tricks to get the right area and the right frame, but having reliable text recognition is more complex.

That's why I would start to train the text recognition function with already cut text areas. The aim is to reach a very good result. Tesseract is probably the best library to do that. Nevertheless, the background is an image, so it is important to check that the text recognition is correct on hundred pictures.

In addition to that, I would recommend starting with 200 random pictures, instead of 10 000. Very often, you can find many mistakes with a first small sample that you could correct, without processing the whole data. Then you increase progressively the amount because there are always unexpected special cases (ex: a life bar with text in the text's background).

It could be interesting to apply object detection to get the bottom menu coordinates, as the text position may differ with screen resolution. But it could be even simple to consider the window size and consider the bottom menu positions as size percentages. Consider also all kinds of user settings (ex: removal of the bottom menu, change of the background transparency, etc.).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, that was what I needed. About train tesseract you must mean this: Train Tesseract LSTM with make from Single Line Images and Groundtruth Transcription / https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesstrain. Right?

Comment: You're welcome. I meant the one from google, but I don't know the one you've mention: it could be better.

See:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract#for-developers

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Command-Line-Usage.html#simplest-invocation-to-ocr-an-image